# Cant Run or Debug Kotlin In IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

since Jetbrains released a new version of IJ, i removed my old version and installed (2017.3.4) the final version !! but when i start a new kotlin project i don't have Run/Debug on my right click !! and when i click on Run from Run menu it gives me a small window that says [Run:Edit Configuration] !! i haven't seen something like this before!! and by the way when i enable the REPL from kotlin sub menu it shows an error :

You’re running the REPL with outdated classes !!

i reinstalled it but its still the same.....even removed the java...nothing changed.
help me please, attached a screenshot....

screen shot from IJ

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify how your project is setup, what version of kotlin you are using etc.

Comment: create project > java > Kotlin JS.....and my kotlin is the default version @jrtapsell

Comment: Can you try adding a main method and see if the run button appears if you make it with java kotlin rather than js

Comment: thank you so much for the solution....i'm in your debt @jrtapsell

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to run or debug because you have written nothing in your class. 
[.This screenshot shows how to add run configuration for your js file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7qq0.png)

[This second link is screenshot of simple Hello World program and you get run/ debug option when you right click on class, go through it please.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVniu.png)

I hope this helps, if you find it useful then upvote please.

Comment: i wrote the code in java > kotlin JVM , however my kotlin > kotlin JS still not working even when i add the main method !!....anyway thank you so much for your answer @Adya

Comment: Can you please attach screenshot of what you have written? @SinaShahriary

Comment: Check this solution, I hope this will help you out. @SinaShahriary